# Android Beautiful login form

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement a login form. I tried it using different layouts, but I am unable to make a login form like the image below.

```
==================================================================================
=
=
=
=
=
=                     =============================================
=                     =                                           =
=                     =  User Name:      Input box                =
=                     =                                           =
=                     =                                           =
=                     =                                           =
=                     =  Password :      Input box                =
=                     =                                           =
=                     =============================================
=
=
=
=
=
=
=
==========================================================================================
```

I tried grid layout but when i draw the central part of username and password's backgroud. I used the gridlayout there also and as a result the output screen goes out of range. (mean I can't) see the full screen.
Here is my xml code .

```
<GridLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/firstdesktop"
android:columnCount="3"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:rowCount="3"
tools:context=".SplitActivity" >




<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="560dp"
    android:layout_height="291dp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rowCount="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_row="0"

        android:text="@string/txtUserName"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_row="0"

        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2.0"
        android:text="@string/txtPass"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:background="@drawable/redbutton"
        android:text="@string/btnLogin" />


    <Space
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_row="1" />
</GridLayout>
```

and here is my emulator properties.
Target Android 4.1 - API Level16
SD Card : Size: 500Mib
Skin: Resolution : 1280 x 800

i have settled emulator screen size according to my tablet size. (1280 x 800)
If there is any other way then tell me..?
kindly help me if u can.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.You are trying it in `GridLayout`. Try to use `RelativeLayout` in the following manner.

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="137dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10" />
```

Comment: For more information read this post about layout's in Android http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/

Comment: but how can i put the inner rectangular background behind the username and password texts and input boxes.

Comment: for that you have to use images for the `EditText` so that you will get what you want.Use this command `android:background="@drawable/yourImageName"` for using image.

Comment: i know but if use image in edit text . than it will only appear behind the edit text... i want to put image behind the inner rectangular.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the inner rectangle as a seperate layout and set the background to that layout.